# Collecting average frequency data of a song/audio recording

Tags: audio, frequency, sound

I'm a university student, and for one of our classes we have to use TouchDesigner to make some sort of dynamic visualizers. I know how to do this already, but to make the process more scientific I wanted to acquire some data that can be used to justify how I calibrated the visualizer.

I'm not really sure how I can begin this process, but where can I begin to dissect a track to gain information and data about the average frequencies that the track is made of? For lack of a better term, spread out the track's audio data onto a graph. Then, I want to compare and contrast the average frequencies of multiple tracks.

I know that there is a proper methodology to do this, but many of the videos on YouTube imply you already have sound engineering knowledge. What should I be searching for specifically for this type of data collection, and how can I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of how to go from the time domain to the frequency domain? Do you know what a power spectrum is for example?

Comment: I say you should start by defining what an “average frequency” is first. Is it like getting a bunch of frequencies in each track and then getting their mean? Is it like you get all the frequencies in the track (like @Jdip indirectly suggested in their comment) get the average of the spectrums and **then** find the dominant frequencies (as many as you’d like)? At least to me, this is not very clear in your answer. Other than that, I think @Jdip’s comment is to the point. You have to get frequencies out of time-domain data to get any kind of averaged frequency. So please clarify that.

Comment: I wasn't sure how specific I had to be. As an example in the most layman terms possible, I'm interested in seeing the how a song "looks" on a graph, akin to a spectrum analyzer. The X would be the frequency and the Y, I assume would be "how often" that frequency is being played through the track. Again, I'm sorry if that isn't a great description as I am not familiar with the jargon yet.

Comment: Well then, if I understood correctly, this seem to be the frequency spectrum of the frequency appearance. There is some problem with this, because for non-infinite signals (or for those for which the window/frame size is not an integral multiple of their period) you will get all frequencies in the spectrum. Thus, you’d have to set a threshold below which you consider the frequency to **not** be excited. I suggest you add those details in your question and then someone might be able to formulate an answer.